# Read system call returns wrong number of bytes

Tags: c++, linux, system, call, stdio

I'm trying to implement the `fread` using read system call. I'm using a JPEG file that is 4264394 bytes to test my code. I'm using a user buffer and a file class buffer. If the user buffer is bigger that class buffer, then the data is read directly into the user buffer. if the user buffer is less than the file class buffer, then I'm reading the data first into the file buffer, as soon as it gets filled, I copy it into the user buffer and re-read from file.

My problem is that if I try to read the JPEG file directly by setting the file class buffer to a smaller value than the user buffer, the file is read directly into the user buffer and the size is correct as 4264394 bytes. However, if I tried to use the file class buffer by setting it to a larger value than the user buffer, I get some weird behavior and read seems to mis-read the file size. I'm using a file class buffer of 8192 bytes and a user buffer of 1024 so the file class buffer is exactly 8 times the user buffer.

```
size_t File::fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb) {

    off_t lseekk=0;
    lseekk = lseek(this->fd_, 0 , SEEK_CUR);
    cout << "lseek at begining is " << lseekk << endl;

    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    char* pChar;
    pChar = (char *) ptr;

    cout << "fread started" << endl;
    int flush;

    if (this->buf_state == WRITING) {
        flush = this->fflush(); // make sure to empty the buffer before starting to read
        if (flush == 0) {
            cout << "Flush successful" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Nothing to flush" << endl;
        }
    }

    this->buf_state = READING;

    if (nmemb < (size_t) bufsiz) {
        if (cur_buf_size == 0) {
            cout << "No data buffered" << endl;

            lseekk = lseek(this->fd_, 0 , SEEK_CUR);
            cout << "lseek before read is " << lseekk << endl;
            cur_buf_size = read(this->fd_, this->buf, this->bufsiz);

            lseekk = lseek(this->fd_, 0 , SEEK_CUR);
            cout << "lseek after read is " << lseekk << endl;

            if ((size_t)cur_buf_size < nmemb) { // in case no data buffered and the total size of file is less than nmemb
                nmemb = cur_buf_size;
            }


            if (cur_buf_size < 0) {
                perror("Error Reading File");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                cout << "file reading successful, number of bytes read is: " << cur_buf_size << endl;

                for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
                    //char c;
                    char c = (char) buf[i];
                    pChar[i] = c;
                }
                buf = buf + nmemb;
                cur_buf_size = cur_buf_size - nmemb;


                return nmemb;
            }

        } else if ((cur_buf_size > 0) && (nmemb <= (size_t)cur_buf_size)) {
            cout << "enough data buffered, will not call read" << endl;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
                char c = (char) buf[i];
                pChar[i] = c;
            }
            buf = buf + nmemb;
            cur_buf_size = cur_buf_size - nmemb;
            return nmemb;

        } else if (cur_buf_size > 0 && nmemb > (size_t)cur_buf_size) {
            int nmemb2 = nmemb;

            cout << "not enough data buffered, will call read to re-fill buffer" << endl;
            int remaining = cur_buf_size;

            buf = buf + remaining; // moving buffuer forward to start reading after the remianing chars

            cur_buf_size = read(this->fd_, this->buf, (this->bufsiz - remaining));
            if (cur_buf_size == -1){
              return remaining;
            }

            cur_buf_size = cur_buf_size + remaining;

            buf = buf - remaining; // reverting buffer again to where it was
            if ((size_t)cur_buf_size < nmemb) {
                nmemb2 = cur_buf_size;
                for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
                    char c = (char) buf[i];
                    if (c == ' ') {
                        pChar[i] = ' ';
                    } else {
                        pChar[i] = c;
                    }
                }
                buf = buf + nmemb;
                cur_buf_size = cur_buf_size - nmemb;
                return nmemb2;
            }

            cout << "cur_buf_size is " << cur_buf_size << endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
                char c = (char) buf[i];
                if (c == ' ') {
                    pChar[i] = ' ';
                } else {
                    pChar[i] = c;
                }
            }
            buf = buf + nmemb;
            cur_buf_size = cur_buf_size - nmemb;
            return nmemb2;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "no double buffering, reading/writing data directly to/from the source/destination." << endl;
        bytes_read = read(this->fd_, ptr, nmemb);
        if (bytes_read < 0) {
            perror("Error Reading File");
            exit(1);
        }
        return bytes_read;
    }
    return bytes_read;
}
```

This is the part in my main where I'm opening the file and reading it:

```
total_bytes_read = 0;
int chunk_size4 = 1024;
const char *name4 = "20190211_070835.jpg";
const char * mode4 = "r";
File * f4 = new File(name4, mode4);
char *ubuf4 = new char[chunk_size4];

while (true) {
bytes = f4->fread(ubuf4, 1, chunk_size4);
cout << bytes << endl;
if (bytes < 0) {
    perror("Error Reading File");
    exit(1);
}
if (bytes == 0) {
    cout << "Total Bytes Read is: " << total_bytes_read << endl;
    total_bytes_read=0;
    break;
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < chunk_size; i++) {
        //cout << ubuf[i];
    }
    //cout << endl;
}
total_bytes_read = total_bytes_read + bytes;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 File opened r, File Descriptor is 6
 lseek at begining is 0
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 0
 lseek after read is 8192
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 8192
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 8192
 lseek after read is 16384
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 16384
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 16384
 lseek after read is 24576
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 24576
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 24576
 lseek after read is 32768
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 32768
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 32768
 lseek after read is 40960
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 40960
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 40960
 lseek after read is 49152
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 49152
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 49152
 lseek after read is 57344
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 57344
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 57344
 lseek after read is 65536
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 65536
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 65536
 lseek after read is 73728
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 73728
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 73728
 lseek after read is 81920
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 81920
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 81920
 lseek after read is 90112
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 90112
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 90112
 lseek after read is 98304
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 98304
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 98304
 lseek after read is 106496
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 106496
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 106496
 lseek after read is 114688
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 114688
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 114688
 lseek after read is 122880
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 122880
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 122880
 lseek after read is 131072
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 8192
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 131072
 fread started
 No data buffered
 lseek before read is 131072
 lseek after read is 134048
 file reading successful, number of bytes read is: 2976
 1024
 lseek at begining is 134048
 fread started
 enough data buffered, will not call read
 1024
 lseek at begining is 134048
 fread started
 not enough data buffered, will call read to re-fill buffer
 928
 lseek at begining is 134048
 fread started
 0
 Total Bytes Read is: 134048
```

Output shows that the fread is working fine by reading 8192 bytes off the file every time, passing these to the user buffer in 8 chunks of 1024 then reading again. at one point, it decides to read only a small chunk and then `EOF`.

I tried to run my code on a different linux machine and I got a different number of bytes read. Any idea what could be wrong? Is it my code or read system call is misbehaving?

Last I checked using `lseek` at the beginning of the file, the `lseek(this->fd_, 0 , SEEK_END)` returns 4264394 bytes which means that the OS can see that the file is 4264394 bytes.

Wondering what might be wrong?

Comment: How does `this->buf` get reset if `cur_buf_size` drops to exactly 0?  (Why would you store a moving pointer and several sizes rather than just having multiple pointers, one of which is always at the beginning?)